# How to check second-hand ICOM IC-718?

Tags: hf, icom, equipment

I’m buying a used IC-718 from a local ham. I can verify its function before I decide to buy. I’ve read the manual and know the functions and capabilities.

What should I check / look for, apart from obviously testing its Rx/Tx?

Answer (score 2):

If you have or can borrow a 100W dummy load and a wattmeter, you might want to check to see if the rig can transmit at its full rated power over the range of bands of interest, and without obvious overheating or smelling anything inside (aged caps?) burning.  If you have a pocket HF receiver, you might also be able to check to see if the rig is transmitting obvious spurious harmonics into the dummy load.